# How does Ruby syntax for inputting arguments work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
```

The method signature of password_field is:

```
      def password_field(object_name, method, options = {})
```

1. In the "... f.password_field :password..." line, are two arguments getting passed into password_field? So it's the same as "f.password_field(:password, class: 'form-control')?
2. According to the method signature of pw_field, ":password" should be an object. However, it's a symbol which as I understand is more like a string than a pointer. How does inputting this as an object make sense?
3. Why is the "class: 'form-control'" argument a method? It doesn't seem like a method to me, but it's not a hash so I assume it should not be the "options" in the method signature...

Answer (score 1):

> In the "... f.password_field :password..." line, are two arguments
>   getting passed into password_field? So it's the same as
>   "f.password_field(:password, class: 'form-control')?

`f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control'` - here you pass two arguments to f.password_field function

> According to the method signature of pw_field, ":password" should be
>   an object. However, it's a symbol which as I understand is more like a
>   string than a pointer. How does inputting this as an object make
>   sense?

It is not an object, is `object_name` object **name**

> Why is the "class: 'form-control'" argument a method? It doesn't seem
>   like a method to me, but it's not a hash so I assume it should not be
>   the "options" in the method signature..

`class: 'form-control'` it is not a method, is an argument, also is a hash.

> How does "class: 'form-control'" get evaluated into HTML (and what
>   resource tells me how that happens)?

With [`FormBuilder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html). It's generate the html under the hood and use `"class: 'form-control'"` argument to set the class.

> Also with object_name, is the object name automatically a pointer to
>   an object?

`object_name`  it is a name of the attribute of the model which you're using. `password_field` function do not know, the form builder know.

I suggest you to read [`Ruby Basic`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/)

Comment: How does "class: 'form-control'" get evaluated into HTML (and what resource tells me how that happens)?

Comment: Also with object_name, is the object name automatically a pointer to an object? Or must all objects have unique names? I am wondering how password_field function knows what to do

Comment: How does Ruby determine when a comma means a new method or a new argument? For example, this line: f.password_field arg1, arg2   could also mean passing in two arguments into the password_field function

Comment: because `f.password_field arg1, arg2` works exactly as this `f.password_field(arg1, arg2)`, its like the ruby works.

Comment: So how do we know in the original code "class: 'form-control'" is not arg2 to password_field function?

Comment: @Richard it's unlcear for me what you didn't understand, it's how programming language works, it's semantic of that programming language, it's how interpritator works. I can't give you anwers because it's out of that question.

Comment: So actually here: <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
 You are passing two arguments into f.password_field, I see now. How would you have two functions within one <%= ... %> ? Or does it not make sense to put two functions in one of those embedded ruby brackets

Comment: what you mean in one `<%= ... %>` its erb?.